# html scroll to flickers page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why when a user clicks a link in the list does it cause the browser to flicker? This seems to be very apparent when a user clicks the same 'link' twice. Is there a way for me to remove this from happening?

It also appears to happen if you click a link that scrolls upwards instead of down. To test this click the list item '**Test**' and then click '**Why**'

https://jsfiddle.net/JokerMartini/9vne9423/

Here is the main JS bits which are doing all the work...

**JS**

```
function scroll_to_element(element) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(element).offset().top}, 500);
}

$(window).ready(function() {

    $(".nav-title").click(function() {
        var target = $(this);

        // get data-filter text
        var title = target.data('title').toLowerCase();

        // collect section titles
        sections = $( ".section-title" );

        // loop through and scroll to valid section
        for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) { 
            var section = $(sections[i]);
            var section_title = section.data('title').toLowerCase();

            if (section_title === title) {
                scroll_to_element(section)
                // console.log(target);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should [prevent the default behavior](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) of the anchor tag before invoking your custom functionality:

```
$(".nav-title").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vne9423/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

put `href="javascript:void(0);"` instead of `href="#"` attribute  in your "What is", "Why" and "Test1" links

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vne9423/7/)

Comment: why though? Could you please explain the reasoning?

Comment: From the one side,  `event.preventDefault()` is the best option here because it was developed exactly to prevent default behavior (like jumping to the top of the page in this case) . And `javascript:void(0)` violates [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Security/CSP) on CSP-enabled HTTPS pages.
On the other side, using of `href="javascript:void(0)"` can have some advantages. The best description of this approach you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/138233/2584305)